# Late 1980s shooter arcade game with a flying robot

Tags: identify-this-game, arcade

I am trying to find the name of an arcade shoot em up game (vertical scroller).

The game is probably from the early 1990s or late 1980s. It had a flying robot that would shoot bullets (round bullets) with its one arm and had different power ups including a shield and larger round ball bullets etc. It is similar to the 1942 shooter but instead of an aeroplane it was a flying robot that you could move left and right with the joystick.

Comment: is that vertical scroller or horizontal, or both? Side Arms?

Comment: Hi, It is a vertical scroller But not Side Arms, good guess but it is not that game unfortunately...Thank you

Comment: That's not a lot of information to go on.  Do you remember anything about the arcade cabinet design, color scheme, sound effects, or other distinctive features that would help narrow it down?

Answer (score 2):

The game Cybattler meets that description.

http://www.hardcoregaming101.net/cybattler/

Gameplay video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FteH8cHTkBQ

Comment: Thank you for the above but unfortunately it is not Cybattler, I took a look at he screenshotd of Cybattler & the video link you sent, good guess but that is not the game...Thank you in any case...

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Finalizer from Konami (1985)?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01veAEkZTYA

Answer (score 1):

[UFO Robo Dangar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_Robo_Dangar) (Nichibutsu, 1986) may be it?

You start as a core fighter accompanied by chest and leg flyers, which form a robot.

YouTube video: [UFO Robo Dangar. [Arcade - Nichibutsu]. (1987). Loops?. Until Death.](https://youtu.be/M17E5gRJLwA)